# Azure Update Management missing updates

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I have started to use [Azure Update Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-update-management), but I am finding that it is missing updates, which show up when I go into the VM I am running it against, then to Windows Updates.

For Example, in Azure Update Management, for VM1 I can see the following as outstanding:
[image]

But if I log into VM1 and open Windows Update, I see the following:
[image]

But isn't the Update Management showing these updates, which are available if I go into the VM.

I have also noticed that for some VM's, Azure Update Management reports that during the scheduled deployment, a certain KB has successfully installed, but if I log into the VM and go to Windows Update, it shows as available to be installed.